# Barrier not working with viewstub, too much padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, viewstub

I am trying to use a barrier in combination with a viewstub which inflates a textinputlayout. The problem is that when the text error is set (e.g the user put something wrong in it), the padding gets absolutely messed up. I will provide the code and the screenshots.

### Viewstub usage

```
<ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/app_default_company_name_et"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/app_default_company_name_et"
            android:layout="@layout/app_standard_textinputlayout"
            android:visibility="@{cValidator.companySwitchState}"
            app:hint="@{cValidator.etCompanyNameHint}"
            app:iType="@{0x00000001}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/app_default_company_ust_et"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/margin_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calibrate_user_data_company_text"
            app:mText="@{cValidator.etCompanyName}"
            app:mTextListener="@{cValidator.onCompanyNameChanged}"
            app:vBility="@{cValidator.companySwitchState}"
            app:vForm="@{cValidator.etCompanyNameEM}" />

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/app_default_company_ust_et"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/app_default_company_ust_et"
            android:layout="@layout/app_standard_textinputlayout"
            android:visibility="@{cValidator.companySwitchState}"
            app:hint="@{cValidator.etCompanyCodeHint}"
            app:iType="@{0x00000001}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/margin_right"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/app_default_company_name_et"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/app_default_company_name_et"
            app:mText="@{cValidator.etCompanyCode}"
            app:mTextListener="@{cValidator.onCompanyCodeChanged}"
            app:vBility="@{cValidator.companySwitchState}"
            app:vForm="@{cValidator.etCompanyCodeEM}" />
        
        <com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_intern_salutation_menu_dd"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/app_standard_fullName_et"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/margin_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_barrier"
            app:validate_form="@{cValidator.ddSalutationEM}">

            <com.example.app.presentation.util.view.ExposedDropDown
                android:id="@+id/calibrate_user_data_salutation_dropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tv_dropdown_height"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_text_large"
                app:dropdown_adapter="@{@stringArray/app_contact_form_headline_salutation_choice}"
                app:dropdown_behavior="@{cValidator.salutationDropDownBehavior}"
                app:dropdown_text="@{cValidator.ddSalutation}" />

        </com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout>

<com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_standard_fullName_et"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/app_contact_form_full_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/margin_right"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/app_intern_salutation_menu_dd"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/app_intern_salutation_menu_dd"
    app:validate_form="@{cValidator.etFullNameEM}">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@={cValidator.etFullName}"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_text_large" />

</com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/company_barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="app_default_company_name_et,
            app_default_company_ust_et" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/margin_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/margin_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/spacing_large" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/middleMargin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### Viewstub inflated layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1" />

        <import type="kotlin.Unit" />

        <variable
            name="vBility"
            type="Boolean" />

        <variable
            name="vForm"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="hint"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="iType"
            type="Integer" />

        <variable
            name="mText"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="mPrefixText"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="mEndIcon"
            type="Integer" />

        <variable
            name="mTextListener"
            type="Function1&lt;String,Unit>" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="@{vBility}">

        <com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_default_et"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@{hint}"
            android:visibility="@{vBility}"
            app:endIconMode="@{mEndIcon}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:prefixText="@{mPrefixText}"
            app:validate_form="@{vForm}">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/app_default_ed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="@{iType}"
                android:text="@{mText}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_text_large"
                app:onTextChanged="@{mTextListener}" />

        </com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### Picture: without error set

[image]

### Picture: with error set

Automatically adds 200dp padding (value from layout inspector)
[image]

The only way I could solve this problem was to not use barriers anymore, but I would like to continue using them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve this problem. I had to delete the `constraintlayout` from my `viewstub_inflated_layout`. Here is the solution

```
<data>

    <import type="kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1" />

    <import type="kotlin.Unit" />

    <variable
        name="vBility"
        type="Boolean" />

    <variable
        name="vForm"
        type="String" />

    <variable
        name="hint"
        type="String" />

    <variable
        name="iType"
        type="Integer" />

    <variable
        name="mText"
        type="String" />

    <variable
        name="mPrefixText"
        type="String" />

    <variable
        name="mEndIcon"
        type="Integer" />

    <variable
        name="mTextListener"
        type="Function1&lt;String,Unit>" />
</data>

<com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_default_et"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@{hint}"
    android:visibility="@{vBility}"
    app:endIconMode="@{mEndIcon}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:prefixText="@{mPrefixText}"
    app:validate_form="@{vForm}">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/app_default_ed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="@{iType}"
        android:text="@{mText}"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_text_large"
        app:onTextChanged="@{mTextListener}" />

</com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout>
```